# Roku cast sample code for handling player controls

Tags: casting, roku, brightscript

I wanted to implement roku cast for one of channel.

I found little information for roku casting using DIAL protocol. Using [DIAL Protocol](http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-protocol-specification) documentation I can implement channel launch and stop.

But I want to know how to handle player controls(pause, volume controls etc) from the second screen application(Mobile). It would be so helpful if I get documentation and sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using **ROKU ECP**:

**ROKU ECP:** *The External Control Protocol (ECP) enables a Roku device to be controlled over a local area network by providing a number of external control services.*

I think the ROKU documentation contains all necessary information for You to implement external ROKU controls.
In the docs You can also find small snippets of code and CURL examples.

[ROKU ECP DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/debugging/external-control-api.md).

Comment: Yes, I followed the same documentation. But I want code samples for handling the player controls on casting by using DIAL protocol. I want to know what is the url to be called for handling the controls from mobile. And observers for the same in roku application